# Risk of installing Debian as a secondary OS

Tags: windows-7, operating-system, debian

Are there any risks when installing Debian as a secondary OS? Win7 is my primary OS and I need absolute acces to that OS because I use it for work. I simply wouldn't like to screw something up during the installation of Debian and see that I can't acces Win7 either.

Are there any risks like that?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try USB booting Debian? That way Debian will run off the USB and you won't risk anything on your work computer.

Follow the link to see how to boot via USB:

https://wiki.debian.org/BootUsb

Comment: I am not sure if debian would work at the same speed when booted from USB. Plus I have no usb device with such space. I wanted to install all three Debian ISOs, which is equal to about 12GB of data.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to install three Debian ISOs but I have dual/triple boot setups on my computers with no issues. Backup your windows before installing Debian just in case

Comment: I also have a dual boot setup - Win7 and WinXP. The problem is that Linux needs a different bootloader and if I screw something up and GRUB will overwrite the bootloader will there be a possibility to bring Windows bootloader back?

EDIT: Now I realized I should have asked that last question as a main question. Though still I am interrested in some additional risks when installing Debian as a secondary OS.